# CSS only applies to widescreen devices, not mobile in Magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1, css

CSS only applies to widescreen devices, not mobile. This isn't reponsive because when I use F12 in the browser and select the reponsive mode, it still has css but when reloading on it it no longer shows that css. I don't know what this is? How to fix it?

Comment: are you using the RWD theme?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, add your CSS inside this block

```
@media (min-width:1281px)
{
 ....
 /* your css code */
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use media query for it. Learn about media query [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

You can use snippet below with necessary changes.

```
@media (min-width:1281px)
{
    // Change min-with value according your requirement
    // Your CSS here
}
```

Hope it will helps you.